# Running without a display manager

Tags: display-manager

As I understand it the display manager asks you to pick an `xsession` and log in.

I'm running `icewm` on Ubuntu 22.04 an old machine and just need it to start up and start `icewm` automatically -- no need for display managers or passwords.

I've switched from `gdm3` to `ligntgdm` (`xdm` doesn't work) but can I remove the display manager completely since it is entirely useless?

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu?